# Comparing garbage generation in Java

Tags: java, testing, garbage-collection, jvm

I'm looking for tools that will let me measure and compare the amount of garbage generated by certain code on the JVM.

I'm aware that tools like YourKit will allow tracking of allocations, but using that tool is very clicky-clicky. (Change code, run with agent, enable tracking, run actual code, take snapshot, etc) It requires a lot of my time/work per iteration.

I'm ideally looking for something like a microbenchmark suite, where it's easy to tweak something and take a new measurement. But instead of measuring speed, I'm interested in measuring allocations.